# How to force WebView to skip images?

Tags: android, webview

Can someone advice me how to tune up Android WebView to skip images from remote server (without image placeholders)

Comment: If you dont want placeholders, I suppose you can strip <img> tags and it's content from HTML on load.

Comment: Yepp, its obvious solutions, I'm thinking of possible to set some property of something to make WebView not look for images

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try using :

```
webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(false);
```

Answer (score 6):

```
webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(false);
webView.getSettings().setBlockNetworkLoads (true);
```

Comment: Explanation to both the function apart from format doc would be +1

Answer (score 3):

```
webView.getSettings().setBlockNetworkImage(true);
```

and in webview onPageFinished

```
webView.loadUrl("javascript:(function(){ var imgs=document.getElementsByTagName('img');"+
                         "for(i=0;i<imgs.length;i++) { imgs[i].style.display='none'; } })()");
```

Answer (score 0):

In onCreate `webView.getSettings().setBlockNetworkImage(true);`

In onPageFinished of WebViewClient `webView.getSettings().setBlockNetworkImage(false);`